# precision recall pos_label python for one-class

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, precision-recall

**Goal**: Obtain `precision` and `recall` for **one-class**(`y_true` = `1`)

**Background**: I checked http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html#sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve and it states that `pos_label` is the label for the `positive class`, and is set to `1` by default.

**Questions**:

1) If I only want the `precision` and `recall` for my `positive class` (`y_true` = `1` in this case) should I keep `pos_label` = `1` or should I change it to `pos_label = 0`?

2) Or is there a better way to accomplish my **Goal**?

Below I am showing code when `pos_label` = `0`

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support
y_true = np.array(['0', '1', '1', '0', '1'])
y_pred = np.array(['1', '0', '1', '0', '1'])
out = precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true, y_pred, average='weighted', pos_label = 0)
```

Comment: Fairly certain pos_label should be 1.  You could always run the code and [calculate precision and recall by hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix).

Comment: Have you tried using the [classification_report](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html)?

Comment: I have used the classification_report. But the issue is getting the scores for `one-class.` What I use `target-names?` or how would you recommend I accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean by one-class? classification report by default will output the metrics for all the classes individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support
y_true = np.array(['0', '1', '1', '0', '1'])
y_pred = np.array(['1', '0', '1', '0', '1'])

#keep 1's
y_true, y_pred = zip(*[[ytrue[i], ypred[i]] for i in range(len(ytrue)) if ytrue[i]=="1"])

out = precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true, y_pred, average='micro')
```